# Снтаксический разбор вопросительного предложения

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Три предложения:

1) Что такое кошка?
2) Кошка это что?
3) Кошка — что это такое вообще?

Где подлежащее, сказуемое и прочие члены?

Свои варианты предлагать не буду, т. к. хочу увидеть мнения других людей в чистом виде, а не степень согласия с моим мнением.

Comment: Скажите — где, и получите ответ: правильно или нет.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что д/з

Comment: Нужно привести свои мысли, иначе вопрос считается дз и закрывается.

Comment: Привести свои ответы, конечно, желательно,  но вопрос нестандартный, интересный, делить его на отдельные  вопросы не нужно, так как они связаны между собой одной темой.

Comment: Согласен с Ариной, вопрос интересный. Зря закрыли!

Comment: Я бы даже расширил этот вопрос.
А что кошка?
И что же, кошка?
Кошка, ты что?
Что ты, кошка!
А кошке-то что?
Кошка, ты, что ли?

Comment: @Arina, Alex_ander, slava1947 друзья! Если вы считаете, что вопрос должен быть переоткрыт — проголосуйте за переоткрытие (кнопка рядом с тревогой). P. S. Действительно, предложения можно не разбивать на три вопроса — посмотрел мельком, виноват.

Comment: Это не д/з. Если модераторы считают, что тему следует удалить, то мне всё равно. Свои варианты предлагать не буду, т.к. хочу увидеть мнения других людей в "чистом виде", а не степень согласия с моим мнением.

Comment: Благодарю за уточнение. Если бы вы сразу указали это в вопросе, было бы проще.

Comment: «...Мне всё равно» (удалят или нет), «не буду, т. к. хочу». ======== С людями надо помягше, Маша!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**В качестве варианта:**

**1) Что такое кошка?**  Кошка  — подлежащее, **что такое** — сказуемое.

**ТАКОЙ**,  местоим. прил. 1. **Схожий с этим, подобный данному или тому, о ком или о чём говорилось.** Т. учитель не нужен нам.  **Кто т.?** (вопрос о ком-л. неизвестном).

Семантика вопроса: На какой предмет похожа кошка, с чем ее можно сравнить? Кошка **такая, как что?**

**2) Кошка — это что?**

Кошка — подлежащее, это — связка, что — сказуемое.

Сравнить: Кошка — это животное? Да, кошка — это животное.

**3) Кошка — что это такое вообще?**

Кошка — именительный темы. Что такое — сказуемое, это — подлежащее, вообще — обстоятельство.

Comment: Интересно, спасибо. А почему во 2м варианте у вас "это" - связка, а в 3м - подлежащее? Конструкция-то одинаковая, просто порядок слов разный!

Comment: Предложения со связкой ЭТО  являются частным видом предложений с именительным темы,(они построены одинаково), но в частном случае ЭТО считается не подлежащим, а связкой. Я только вот сомневаюсь по поводу местоимения "такой", что с ним делать. Возможно, надо смотреть на ответ. Что такое кошка? Кошка - такое животное.  Может быть, слово "такой" лучше считать местоименным определением, отнесенным к сказуемому.

Comment: К первому вопросу два аналога: а) вообще=именно; что именно есть кошка? б) что кошкою зовется? Мое мнение было: что - подлежащее, т.к. речь не о кошке, а о том, что ею зовется; "есть кошка" - сказуемое. "есть" пропущено, осталась кошка.  А в примере б) кошка явно не подлежащее. :)

Comment: Что в имени тебе моем? -  А что здесь подлежащее, сказуемое?

Comment: Это эллиптическое двусоставное предложение. ЧТО - подлежащее, В ИМЕНИ - дополнение. Сказуемое в таких предложениях отсутствует, но может определяться по смыслу. Смысл такой: Что заключено в моем имени для тебя?  Тревога, сомнение, любовь - или ничего?  Но сравним с похожим предложением: Что я для тебя? Здесь Я - подлежащее, ЧТО - сказуемое. Так сходное содержание мы выражаем разными грамматическими формами.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы разбирал так...

> 1) ***Что такое кошка?*** (*= Что есть кошка?*)

***Кошка*** —  подлежащее; ***что такое*** —  сказуемое.

> 2) ***Кошка это что?***

Здесь нужно тире: ***Кошка — это что?***

***Кошка*** —  именительный представления; ***это***  — подлежащее; ***что*** —  сказуемое.

> 3) ***Кошка — что это такое вообще?***

***Кошка*** —  именительный представления; ***это***  — подлежащее; ***что такое*** —  сказуемое; ***вообще*** (= в большей части случаев)  — обстоятельство.

Comment: Что в имени тебе моем? - А здесь что чем является? :)

Comment: А здесь _что_ я считал бы подлежащим; сказуемое (=видится, слышится...) — опущено.

Comment: Почему тогда в первом вопросе "что" - не подлежащее, а "(есть) кошка" - не сказуемое? Конструкция одинаковая. "есть" опущено, кошка осталась.

Comment: Ну где же одинаковая-то... В первом предложении два слова стоят в именительном падеже, в предложении  _"Что в имени тебе моем?"_ -- одно... Совсем разные конструкции.

Comment: "что кошкою зовется" и "что есть кошка". В первом варианте подлежащее "что", а почему во 2м варианте предпочтение в выборе переходит на кошку?